Обход графа в Neo4j с использованием свойств узлов и связей
Есть ориентированный граф, состоящий из узлов с метками Node и связями HAS_CHILD. Связи могут иметь свойство deleted_at. Есть задача обойти этот граф и сделать определенные действия с каждым узлом (скажем, копировать). Обходить граф нужно только по связям HAS_CHILD, которые не имеют свойства deleted_at.
Я знаю, что в модуле gds есть методы для bfs и dfs, однако в их конфигурации можно указать только метки для узлов и связей, по которым нужно делать обход, а мне соответственно нужно указывать еще и свойства.
Есть ли готовые инструменты для такого обхода?

Предоставьте код, как Вы пытались это сделать, и что не получилось.
